# How to say "the data collected from the previous month to current timstamp" in the following sentence?

Tags: time

"This validates the observation that historical data with at most one month gap closing up 
to the current timestamp is favored."

Not sure whether the sentece above is correct or not .

I want to refer to the "data from the previous month to current timstamp"

Comment: No, it does not unambiguous mean that.

Comment: Tim has a stamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"At most one month gap" seems to contradict "data from the previous month to current timstamp", as the latter could be more than one month. Are you looking for data from the previous 30 days or data from the 1st of the previous month until today?

*[Month to date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Month-to-date)* is used for the time from the 1st of the current month until the current date.

The terms *[prior month to date](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22prior%20month%20to%20date%22)* and *[previous month to date](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22previous%20month%20to%20date%22)* are not unheard of, and they mean what you're referring to.

Comment: data from the 1st of the previous month until today is what I want.

Comment: Thank you very much.  "prior month to date" is fantastic